# How can initialize a variable into method and how use sleep in jsonrequest

Tags: android, json, android-studio

I have 2 problem.

- Once :

  - I cant initialize a non-final variable inner method.I want to initialize a variable in JsonRequestbut when I use in it shows me a error -create variable final.

    ```
    public DataModel[] getContentsUsername(final int count)  {
       DataModel[] dataModels = new DataModel[count];
       for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
          dataModels[i] = new DataModel();
       }
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest("http://www.lmslfm.isteb.ir/message/json.php", new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        try {

            JSONObject jsonObject ;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                jsonObject = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
                dataModels[i].setMessageContent(jsonObject.getString("message_content"));
                dataModels[i].setMessageUserName(jsonObject.getString("user_name"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

       }
       });
       jsonArrayRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(4000, 0, 0));
       RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
       requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

      return dataModels;
    }
    ```
- and 2 :
  When a app goes to give data from server it takes time and when i want to recieve data from this method i give a empty variable . 
  how can i use codes to recive from method when data recieved from server or after many seconds . 
  thanks

Comment: Implement a callback interface and pass instance in as parameter to getContentsUsername.  Move the DataModel init code inside of the 'onResponse' and in 'onResponse' invoke the callback with the dataModel[] instance.  Your getContentsUsername can't return dataModels because it hasn't been received yet.